# Running Windows Photo Viewer from shortcut for a particular directory?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, windows-photo-viewer

I looked at the `Command Line` column in the Task Manager, and it's `C:\Windows\system32\DllHost.exe /Processid: {76D0CB12-7604-4048-B83C-1005C7DDC503}` so if I want to open that from a shortcut for a particular directory...is there a way to that?

Comment: Does this point you in the correct direction? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190271/how-to-run-photoviewer-dll-in-command-line

Answer (score 1):

You may run the old PhotoViewer app by using this command:

```
rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen path\to\image
```

Note however that this old program does not accept quotes around the path,
so it cannot be used with blanks in folder or image file-name.
For such files, use the old windows style paths,
for example: `C:\folder~1\image~1.bmp`.

You may also use the free
[Winaero Tweaker](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.1836)
to activate PhotoViewer:

[image: Winaero Tweaker - Activate Windows Photo Viewer]